# Одновременно чат + загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, chat

Коллеги, помогите. Сделал чат socket.io+express, по примитивному самому простому примеру от разработчика. Все работает. Надо тут же добавить загружать файлы на сервер. Посмотрел несколько библиотек, реализовал на **delivery**. Загружает нормально. Но чат и загрузка на одном порту, что я сделал наверное не правильно. Если гружу маленький файл то проходит без проблем, если большой, скажем 700кБ и более - чат "отпадает", файл благополучно загружается в любом случае, отпал или нет. После чего через несколько секунд чат восстанавливается. Понятно что ping/pong не проходит, когда файл транслируется. 
Как развести на разные порты? В браузере я явно указываю в URL порт например 3001. Надо сделать отдельный транспорт для чата и для файлов, а вот как это реализовать. Если есть примеры, сообщите плз. Заранее благодарю.

### Серверная сторона:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var dl  = require('delivery');
var fs = require('fs');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('User connected');

    /*### Секция чата ###*/

    //кто то отключился...
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        ...
    }

    //получили / переотправили сообщение
    socket.on('msg', function(msg){
        ...
    }

    /*### Секция приема файлов ###*/

    var delivery = dl.listen(socket);
    delivery.on('receive.success',function(file){
    var params = file.params;
    fs.writeFile(file.name,file.buffer, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log('File could not be saved.');
            }else{
                console.log('File saved.');
            };
        });
    });

}

http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3001\n');
});
```

### Клиентская сторона:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="delivery.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
...
var socket = io();

//если приняли сообщение
socket.on('msg', function(msg){
    ...
});

//если оборвалась/оборвали связь
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    ...
});

//если востановилась/восстановили связь
socket.on('connect', function(){
    ...
});

//отправка файла из поля #file
var delivery = new Delivery(socket);
delivery.on('delivery.connect',function(delivery){
  $('#file').change(function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var extraParams = {foo: 'bar'};
    delivery.send(file, extraParams);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

delivery.on('send.success',function(fileUID){
  console.log("file was successfully sent.");
});
```

Comment: почему бы просто не поднять отдельно сервер для статики ( загрузка/отдача файлов ) и отдельно чат

Comment: Не разу не поднимал так, думал можно совместить, так и сделаю сейчас, отдельно и то и это. Вопрос от сюда. Можно ли так. 80й порт на html страницы, 3000 на чат, 3001 на загрузку файлов? и т.п. Т.е. html и чат разделить.

Comment: Ну обычно ресурсы раздает статика, сокеты с чатом поднимаются на своем порту. Иногда даже на другом сервере